# Python: map overridden method to list of instances

Tags: python

I'd like to map method to list of instances. All instances are of class, inherited from some abstract class with method `Method()`. I can do it easily with list comprehension:

```
[o.Method() for o in list_of_instances]
```

But how to do it using `map()`? I'am trying

```
map(MyAbstractClass.Method, list_of_instances)
```

but it (of cause!) maps empty method of MyAbstractClass instead of overridden one. Is there any way to map overridden one with `map()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `operator.methodcaller`:

```
import operator
map(operator.methodcaller("Method"), list_of_instances)
```

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for?

```
map(lambda x: x.Method(), list_of_instances)
```